# SwiftUI Tab View on iOS like Safari

Tags: ios, swiftui, safari, tabs

macOS has the ability to have several tabs at the top of the window, in Safari and other apps. I've noticed that iOS Safari (on iPad and newer phones) has this ability too.

[image: tabs]

In macOS, it's done like this:

```
struct TabbyCatApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
      let mainWindow = WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
      }
      mainWindow.commands {
        CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
          Button(action: {
            if let currentWindow = NSApp.keyWindow,
              let windowController = currentWindow.windowController {
              windowController.newWindowForTab(nil)
              if let newWindow = NSApp.keyWindow,
                currentWindow != newWindow {
                  currentWindow.addTabbedWindow(newWindow, ordered: .above)
                }
            }
          }) {
            Text("New Tab")
          }
          .keyboardShortcut("t", modifiers: [.command])
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this on iOS? Apple developers are obviously achieving it, but is there a way for humble Johnny Developer to do it?

( note: I'm not talking about the usual UITabBar that goes at the bottom )